# Derivative of a vector times its transpose

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I am trying to work out how to solve a derivative of the form:

$${d \over dx}(M(x)M(x)^T)$$

where M is a vector.

In my case specifically, M is the (1x3) vector

$$M(x)={df(x) \over dx}$$

where f(x) is a scalar and x is a (3x1) vector.

Could I just use the product rule like this:
$${d(uv) \over dx}=u{dv \over dx}+v{du \over dx}$$ 
if $M(x)=u$ and $M(x)^T=v$ then
$${d \over dx}(M(x)M(x)^T)=M(x){d(M(x)^T) \over dx}+M(x)^T{d(M(x)) \over dx}$$ 
$${d \over dx}(M(x)M(x)^T)=M(x){d(M(x)) \over dx}^T+M(x)^T{d(M(x)) \over dx}$$ 
$${d \over dx}(M(x)M(x)^T)={df(x) \over dx}({{d^2 f(x) \over dx^2}})^T+({df(x) \over dx})^T{{d^2 f(x) \over dx^2}}$$

I assume that I made a few mistakes above. Whether you help with the general solution or my problem specifically it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is $M$ a column vector, so that $MM^T$ is a square matrix, or a row vector, so that $MM^T$ is a scalar?

Comment: M is a row vector so that $MM^T$ is a scalar

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not in general commutative, so you have to take care to maintain the order of the terms in a product. The version of the product rule that you’ve used doesn’t do that. Try $(uv)'=uv'+u'v$ instead. In this particular case, though, I think expanding the product by components before differentiating is a much less error-prone way to attack the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M_i=\partial_i f$ with $\partial_i:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, $\sum_j\partial_i M_j^2=2\sum_j M_j\partial_i M_j=2\sum_j\partial_j f\partial_i\partial_j f$, the $i$th component of a vector perhaps best denoted as $2\nabla f\nabla^2 f$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I am not so experienced (yet) in understanding the type of notation that you have used. Is that the same as ${df \over dxi}{df^2 \over dxi^2}$ for i = 1 to 3?

Comment: @SolidMechUK No; in this case $\nabla^2$ creates a matrix. It's clearer if we use the index notation that I had before.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $M$, let's denote the gradient of $f$ by 
$$g=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
And for the Hessian of $f$, let's use
$$H=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\,\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$
Note that $H$ is symmetric.

The function of interest is the square of the gradient. Write it in terms of these new variables and find its differential and derivative.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|g\|^2 = g\cdot g \cr
d\phi &= 2g\cdot dg = 2g\cdot(H\cdot dx) = 2(H^T\cdot g)\cdot dx \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= 2H^T\cdot g = 2H\cdot g \cr
}$$